# JPA: How should I annotate this Map collections?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I will explain myself by giving you a descriptive example. Let's say we are programming a very simple Cloud Storage using JPA, so we have two main classes, `User` and `File` coded as follows:

```
class User {
       List<File> ownFiles;
       Map<File, Integer> sharedFiles; 
}

class File {
       User author;
       Map<User, Integer> sharedUsers;
}
```

**How should I annotate this fields?** I've tried, but I always get `NotSerializableException` *"data too long for column"*.

- By the way, `File` is just an example, my real class is small, only composed of some Strings. So I'm pretty sure the `NotSerializableException` is thrown because of the Map annotations.
- By the way, here you have the meaning of the Maps values,

  - In the case of `User`, the Integer value of the files is representing the permission level of the user over the file
  - And in the case of `File` the Keys are those Users who the file has been shared to and the Value is the permission level of that User over the `File`

P.S: I'm using Eclipselink

Comment: NotSerializableException is because if you haven't annotated it, it will default to a basic mapping and try to serialize the object. Just showing us the collection isn't going to help us tell you how to map it - you need to tell us what you want done with it, where the integer values come from and should be stored etc. Start with any JPA tutorial that shows a ManyToMany mapping.

Comment: Probably engine want to store this field in "brutal", non-relational way (like BLOB/CLOB etc) so try to serialize. Map cannot be stored by JPA in object-relational way. Suggest redesign, project in JPA must keep rules not always consistent with classic OOP, i.e. Map is bad.

Comment: suggest use different class name for File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this tutorial](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/map-with-entity-keys/) I annotated the fields in the following way:

```
class User {
       @OneToMany
       List<File> ownFiles;

       @ElementCollection
       Map<File, Integer> sharedFiles; 
}

class File {
       @ManyToOne
       User author;

       @ElementCollection
       Map<User, Integer> sharedUsers;
}
```

More detailed:

```
class User {
       @OneToMany
       @JoinTable(name = "USER_HAS__OWN_FILES", joinColumns = {
       @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR", referencedColumnName = "USERNAME")}, 
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "OWN_FILE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") })
       List<File> ownFiles;

       @ElementCollection
       @CollectionTable(name = "USER_HAS_SHARED_FILES", joinColumns = 
       @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME", referencedColumnName = "USERNAME"))
       @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "SHARED_FILE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
       @Column(name = "PERMISSION_LEVEL")
       Map<File, Integer> sharedFiles; 
}

class File {
       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "FILE_AUTHOR", referencedColumnName = "USERNAME")
       User author;

       @ElementCollection
       @CollectionTable(name = "FILE_HAS_BEEN_SHARED_TO_USER", 
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FILE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
       @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "USER_THAT_FILE_HAS_BEEN_SHARED_TO", referencedColumnName = "USERNAME")
       @Column(name = "PERMISSION_LEVEL")
       Map<User, Integer> sharedUsers;
}
```

Now it works as I expected, generating the following tables:

- `User (ID, Username, ...)`
- `File (ID, Filename, Author, ...)`
- `User_has_shared_files (Username, Shared_file_id, permission_level)`
- `User_has__own_files (Username, Own_file_id)`
- `File_has_been_shared_to_user (File_id, Username_id, permission_level)`

The `@ElementCollection` annotation is useful to map `Java.Map<Entity, basicType>`

Comment: I've just figured out that this way the data is stored twice in the database, as  User_has_shared_files and File_has_been_shared_to_user are equivalents

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comment, **Map<> cannot be processed by JPA 1.0** in such way (so attempt to serialise occur)

JPA 2.0 added annotations, with many complicated quirts,  delicate attributes **(personal opinion)**
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/ElementCollections
I'm not surprised generated database can be simmilar

In my opinion I have better control over database with JPA 1 way (is cleaner for me). Let me show my proposal.

My clearing of Your logical structure in 1.x philosophy is is:

```
class User {
     // ... fields waht You want
}

class FileEtiquette  {
       User author;
}

class SharingIncident {
  User user;
  FileEtiquette  file;
  int level;
}
```

Maybe I dont understand fully Your nomenclature, so names can be not elegant.

Next attempt, not compiled, example only.

```
    @Entity
    class User {
        @Id
        int id;
        @Basic
        Set<SharingIncident> shares;
        @Basic
        Set<FileEtiquette> myFiles;
         // ... fields waht You want
    }

@Entity
class FileEtiquette  {
    @Id
    int id;
    @Basic
    Set<SharingIncident> sharedBy;
    User author;
}

@Entity
class SharingIncident {
    @Id
    int id;
    User user;
    FileEtiquette  file;
    int level;
}
```

Few remarks.

- Many To Many can be realised in 'automagically' way, but in Your
  example integer field is interesting, worth to design relation
  manually.
- Usually when average programmers think `List<>`  , in JPA    `Set<>` can
  be better
- changing Your `File` name is my personal taste
- It is only basis, many improvements possible, based on my understanding of Your intent. My goal is to show, how replace Map<> in classic way

Next steps possible, let me think a moment

Comment: I'm sure your solution will work properly, but currently I would like to solve it by having a Map with JPA 2.1. If finally I end up using your proposal I will mark your answer as best. Thanks!